# Can Laravel 4 be run without mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4

Our client doesn't have mod_rewrite enabled on the host. Is it possible to run Laravel 4 without it?

The default .htaccess file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If yes, how?

Comment: Yes it will, but the url will be domain.com/index.php/route/to/here instead of domain.com/route/to/here, since it has to route through index.php

Comment: @Noik: domain.com/index.php/ and any sub-routes return a blank page with the 500 HTTP error code (internal server error). Are the (Apache) settings on the host somehow screwed up?

Comment: @randomguy They might, you should check the apache error logs or laravel log to see whats happening. Could be Laravel/PHP throwing an error or apache.